# Spurios NameError for internal classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Every once in a while, a `NameError` is raised in our staging environment (running in Rails `production` mode, Heroku), referring to internal classes of the frameworks.

It didn't cause any real problem so far but I have no idea where this might be coming from. The weirdest part is that the `did_you_mean` functionality is able to find the class just fine.

Two examples from the last couple of days:

```
uninitialized constant Grape::Middleware::Versioner::Path
Did you mean?  Grape::Middleware::Versioner::Path
               Grape::Path
```

and

```
uninitialized constant Mail::ContentTransferEncodingElement
Did you mean?  Mail::ContentTransferEncodingElement
               Mail::ContentTransferEncodingField
```

What is happening here? It feels like some race condition somewhere but since to the best of my knowledge there is no parallel loading possible, that can't very well be the case.

Comment: Does it happen only for certain classes? I assume some code might be loaded before the dependency it relies on. There should be some more information, including backtraces.

Comment: The backtraces show regular request cycles or background jobs being invoked. And it only happens spuriously, but always inside the frameworks (Grape and/or Rails) i.e. without any reference to the application code in the backtrace. It also happens too rarely to determine a real pattern but the affected classes don't seem to have anything in common apart from being outside our applications code.